# Segue and NSString Bug

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, segue

I'm currently making a Note app and ran into a strange problem with segue.

I currently have 
a `Note` object with field of name and description. I then create a note on one view. After 
finish creating that note, the app returns to a table list of all the notes you have. If 
you click on a note within the table list, you are taken to a edit note screen.

The problem I am having is with segue the `NSString`. It's really weird because the name field is fine, it's just the description field. If I am inputing a default text such as `@"default"` then 
the app is fine, but if I give change it to something like textfield.text (`textfield` is an 
`UITextfield`) then the app crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`description` is already a method in `NSObject` so you can't have a property with same name.

you have to rename this to something like descriptionView

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *description;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, but the program still gave me a bad access error. I changed the name though.
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *descriptionView;

Comment: what is the error? try `NString *desc = self.descriptionView.text; [initWithName:self.nameField.text description:desc];` and set a breakpoint to see the value of `desc`

Comment: nvm, find my problem! It was something really silly!! THANKS FOR ALL YOUR HELP! :D

Comment: which line it crashed? it more looks like memory problem for me now. try enable NSZombie to see any over released object